Как правильно скрыть API-keys?
Всем привет. Сейчас разрабатываю pet-проект для получения актуальной погоды по текущей локации, либо по городу.
В общем, у меня там используются два API ключа: один геодекодер и другой для предоставления данных о погоде. У меня дома и комп, и ноут, когда устаю сидеть за компом, то пушу проект в гитхаб и потом иду ложусь на кровать, беру ноут и стягиваю актуальный проект и продолжаю разработку.
В общем, пушатся и Api-keys, которые нужны для запросов. Что делать, чтобы твоими ключами не злоупотребляли? (Вопрос вообще касается даже не конкретно этого случая, а в целом о конфиденциальной  разработки).
Я правильно понимаю, что если добавить файл, где хранятся Api-keys в .gitignore, то мне потом нужно будет этот файл стягивать откуда-то (возможно, создать приватный репозиторий и туда закидывать отдельно этот файл? Потом отдельно стягивать этот файл)?
Проект чистый на HTML/CSS/JS, а ключи храню в файле variables.js.

"стягивать откуда-то" - ну просто скопировать один раз через флешку, например?

Можно переменные среды использовать, правда тогда придётся дублировать ключи API для ноутбука и компьютера

Через переменные окружения. В проекте создаётся файл .env и в нём пишете
api_key=какой_то_ключ

в gitignore добавляем его
*.env

устанавливаем библиотеку
npm install dotenv --save

Импортируем
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

и можно использовать в коде
const api_key = process.env.api_key;

Теперь у вас переменные хранятся в окружении и не попадают в github
Для нового устройства просто скопировать его и добавить

Я хотел изначально использовать dotenv, но он не используется на клиентской части, поэтому решил просто сделать js-файл и там хранить ключи.

@Teoom07 а при чём тут клиентская часть?

@andreymal ну у меня же вся функциональность работает на клиентской части. Запросы осуществляются с помощью функции fetch, а dotenv работает я как понял только в серверной среде (Node JS).

@Teoom07 то есть абсолютно любой клиент может тупо перехватить этот fetch и скопировать из него api-keys? В таком случае весь ваш вопрос не имеет смысла

@andreymal ну это pet-проект и я больше как фронт-разработчик и поэтому не стал серверную часть делать, но вопрос о защите каких-то данных заинтересовал

@Teoom07 для защиты данных нужно как минимум изначально не давать их кому попало, в том числе клиентам

@andreymal а перехват fetch осуществляется типо через Network => file.js => fetch(запрос) ?

@Teoom07 ну типа того, и ещё ничего не мешает открыть вкладку Sources и скопировать api-keys прям оттуда (возможно, придётся повозиться, чтобы найти их там, но это дело времени)

@andreymal спасибо, буду знать эти тонкости!
